# DAX (visual studio) how to switch values between summarized columns

Tags: visual-studio, dax

I've got 3 tables

1. Fact values
2. Plan Values
3. Category table division, type, city and so on

| Division | type |
| --- | --- |
| d1v1 | type1 |
| d1v2 | type1 |
| d1v3 | type2 |
| d1v4 | type3 |

What I need to find is forecast accuracy

The problem is that I want to create one metric which will calculate it, but for now I find a way to calculate it correct by creating 2 and more metrics for type and for division and so on

This is my code to find correct total sum and abs only for division

```
abs = IF(
        HASONEFILTER(CategoryTable[Division],
         ABS(Fact - Plan),
         SUMX(
         SUMMARIZE(CategoryTable,CategoryTable[Division]),
         ABS(Fact - Plan))
)
```

It works correct but only for division. Is it possible to add some code for **type** and other columns?

I Googled and try almost every possible way but it didn't work well for me, adding summarize does not work.

I'm looking for that kind of result

```
abs = ABS(Fact - Plan)
```

| Division | fact | plan | abs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1v1 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| d1v2 | 6 | 2 | 4 |
| d1v3 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| d1v4 | 8 | 10 | 2 |
| Total | 26 | 16 | 16 |

| type | fact | plan | abs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| type1 | 15 | 3 | 12 |
| type2 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
| type3 | 13 | 10 | 3 |
| Total | 35 | 21 | 16 |

I want get that kind of calculation when I'll change columns in OLAP CUBE.

And after all
I will get accuracy = 1 - abs/sum(fact)